# Does Microsoft test manager 2015 come with the Enterprise version of Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visualstudio, mtm

Does Microsoft test manager 2015 come with the Enterprise version of Visual Studio 2015? If not, what version of Visual Studio 2015 includes Test Manager?

Answer (score 1):

In 2015, MTM comes with both Enterprise and Test Professional.  Documentation can be found with a quick search [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635157.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes Microsoft Test Manager is included with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. If it was not installed by default, you can go to Add/Remove Programs > Modify Installation and add it in.

Visual Studio Testing Tools enables development teams ensure higher quality applications and adopt latest testing practices. These Testing tools provide insightful information enabling development teams to reproduce  and fix issues sooner and faster. Ensuring higher quality applications and a better customer experience. In addition, the testing team can be more productive while planning, executing and tracking tests, both with the web-based test tools using Visual Studio Team Services or with the rich experience provided by Visual Studio and Microsoft Test Manager

Read more info at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/12/10/visual-studio-2015-test-tools-getting-started-content/ and see videos at https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Test-Tools-in-Visual-Studio